# Upload Multipart swift Image Upload internal server error 500 in response

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, image-uploading

I migrated to swift 3 for which i have to Upgrade Alamofire to 4, 
Upload image with mulitpart request is working fine in swift 2 and same API with same params getting internal server error 500 in success
here are is swift 2.3 code which is working fine

```
        Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        AppConstants.kAPIBaseURL  + AppConstants.KAPIWidgetUrl + AppConstants.KAPIUpdateUserPhoto,headers: headers,
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData!, name: "image[image]", fileName: "myImage.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "\((UserManager._currentUser?.userID)!)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"id")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "profile_picture".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"upload_to")


        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.responseJSON { (JSON) in
                    let abc   = JSON.result.value as! NSDictionary
                    print(abc)
                    let arrayOfResult = abc["results"] as! NSDictionary
                    let responseMessage = abc["message"] as! String
                    let currentUser: MOUser?
                    currentUser = MOUser.init(object: arrayOfResult)
                    UserManager.setCurrentUser(currentUser)
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                        //Show Alert in UI
                        print("image uploaded");
                        [self.showAlertViewWithTitle(AppConstants.kEmptyString, message: "\(responseMessage)", dismissCompletion: {

                        })]
                    })
                }

            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError);
            }
        }
    );
```

and below is the Swift 3 code with error

```
Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "image[image]", fileName: "myImage.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            multipartFormData.append("\(UserManager._currentUser?.userID)".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "id")
            multipartFormData.append("profile_picture".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "upload_to")


    },
        to: AppConstants.kAPIBaseURL  + AppConstants.KAPIWidgetUrl + AppConstants.KAPIUpdateUserPhoto ,method: .post, headers: headers,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            print(encodingResult)
            switch encodingResult {

            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    print("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    if let info = response as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                        if let links = info["links"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>? {
                            if let imgLink = links["image_link"] as? String {

                                print("LINK: \(imgLink)")

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

                upload.uploadProgress { progress in

                    print(progress.fractionCompleted)
                }

                upload.responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
                    print(response)
                    print(response.data)
                    print(response.debugDescription)
                    print(response.description)
                    print(response.result.description)
                    print(response.response)
                })



            case .failure(let encodingError):
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")

            }//switch

    }
    );
```

Server Error is this

```
SUCCESS: {"status":"500","error":"Internal Server Error"}
SUCCESS
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000123cda0> { URL: https://../api///imageupload } { status code: 500, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 48;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 11 Jan 2017 13:45:59 GMT";
Server = "WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2015-12-16)";
Via = "1.1 vegur";
"X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
"X-Request-Id" = "78cc7e5c-9bc1-4802-beac-15f8f7c4400a";
"X-Runtime" = "0.167883";
```

If Anybody can help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: You wrote that there is a 500 error on server side, but you don't show server code at all, nor the cause of the server error. Showing at least the server error cause may help to understand the issue.

Comment: I dont if it is on server side, because same code in swift 2.3 is working fine while on swift3.0 i am having this error "SUCCESS: {"status":"500","error":"Internal Server Error"}

Comment: You did wrote `getting internal server error 500`...

Comment: Yes, i am getting this as a response @Xvolks

Comment: You might want to use Charles Proxy or some similar app that can show you the raw request. It seems that if it is working fine in 2.3, you must be passing in something different between the two code bases. The raw request would let you see exactly what is different--if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference in this line:

```
multipartFormData.append("\(UserManager._currentUser?.userID)".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "id")`.
```

You don't force unwrap the `UserManager._currentUser?.userID` like you do in the 2.3 version:

```
multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "\((UserManager._currentUser?.userID)!)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"id")
```

So your string for that "id" field is probably something like "Optional("userID")" instead of just the user ID you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks A lot. Exactly this was the problem